# Ploneftp fatal Exited too quickly

Tags: supervisord, plone

After starting daemon of plumi through supervisord. Screenshot of terminal after checking status of supervisorctl is shown here.

[image]

Log ploneftp-stdout---supervisor-mlgou2.log file is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/abhishek/tuts/test/plumi.app/bin/ploneftp", line 21, in + sys.argv[1:])
File "/home/abhishek/tuts/test/plumi.app/eggs/unweb.recipe.ploneftp-0.1-py2.7.egg/unweb/recipe/ploneftp/ctl.py", line 57, in main ploneftp.zope_ftpd.main(args[0])
File "/home/abhishek/tuts/test/plumi.app/eggs/unweb.recipe.ploneftp-0.1-py2.7.egg/unweb/recipe/ploneftp/zope_ftpd.py", line 232, in main ftpd = ftpserver.FTPServer(address, ftp_handler)
File "/home/abhishek/tuts/test/plumi.app/eggs/pyftpdlib-0.7.0-py2.7.egg/pyftpdlib/ftpserver.py", line 3712, in init raise socket.error(msg) socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't running as root, you won't be able to start a server listening to standard low-numbered ports such as 21 (the standard FTP port).

Comment: Please note: there's `sudo` in the original command line.